Could not update timestamps for skipped and discarded samples in javax.sound.sampled using com.tagtraum.ffsampledsp
Im using the FFAudioFileReader class from com.tagtraum.ffsampledsp to decode ogg, mp3 and flac files and get an AudioInputStream. The audio plays just fine, however when I do audio.reset();
i get this:
[mp3float @ 000001b4fa125d80] Could not update timestamps for skipped samples.
[mp3float @ 000001b4fa125d80] Could not update timestamps for discarded samples.

My global variables are:
public AudioInputStream audio;
File file;

here is my Decode function and what I have tried so far:
 public AudioInputStream DecodeFLAC_OGG_MP3() throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
       FFAudioFileReader audioFileReader = new FFAudioFileReader();
       AudioInputStream audio = audioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(this.file);
       AudioFormat baseFormat = audio.getFormat();
       AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
               AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
               baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
               16,
               baseFormat.getChannels(),
               baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
               baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
               false
       );
       AudioInputStream decodedAudio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, audio);
       // Wrap the AudioInputStream with a BufferedInputStream to enable mark/reset
       BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(decodedAudio);
       return new AudioInputStream(bufferedInputStream, decodedFormat, decodedAudio.getFrameLength());
   }

This is what i tried so far to reset my AudioInputStream:
       audio.mark(0);
       audio.reset();  

How can i fix this?

Does markSupported() on AudioFileStream actually return true?

Yes it does return true

It seems the problem was related to how com.tagtraum.ffsampledsp is handling complex audio formats like mp3 by using timestamps. In conclusion I was finally able to successfully reset my AudioInputStream by using library's FFFormatConversionProvider() class and reading all bytes manualy, passing them into a ByteArray and then created an AudioInputStream which fixed the problem.

Consider using markdown to format your posts.

Try calling seek(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) on the FFAudioInputStream (you'll have to cast).
See also here.
